# Command to get details on charge and time remaining for two batteries

Tags: acpi, battery

I have a laptop with two batteries. I would like to get combined details on the two batteries. In particular, I'd like the time remaining before both batteries run out of charge and the percentage charge left in both batteries. Is there a command to do this?

When I run:

```
acpi -b
```

I get the following output:

```
Battery 0: Full, 100%
Battery 1: Discharging, 80%, 05:10:03 remaining
```

So I'd like a command that instead gives me something like:

```
All batteries: Discharging 90%, 10:10:06 remaining
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my script. It depends on `acpi` and `acpitool`

It:

1. Outputs the average percent of all batteries in the device
2. How long it'll take for all batteries to fully charge (if the device is plugged in), or how long until it becomes completely empty (if not plugged in),
3. Says if the device is being charged.

The final output is in the format `All batteries: Discharging 90%, 10:10:06 remaining` (with different numbers and Discharging can be Charging).

```
#!/bin/bash

get_time_until_charged() {

    # parses acpitool's battery info for the remaining charge of all batteries and sums them up
    sum_remaining_charge=$(acpitool -B | grep -E 'Remaining capacity' | awk '{print $4}' | grep -Eo "[0-9]+" | paste -sd+ | bc);

    # finds the rate at which the batteries being drained at
    present_rate=$(acpitool -B | grep -E 'Present rate' | awk '{print $4}' | grep -Eo "[0-9]+" | paste -sd+ | bc);

    # divides current charge by the rate at which it's falling, then converts it into seconds for `date`
    seconds=$(bc <<< "scale = 10; ($sum_remaining_charge / $present_rate) * 3600");

    # prettifies the seconds into h:mm:ss format
    pretty_time=$(date -u -d @${seconds} +%T);

    echo $pretty_time;
}

get_battery_combined_percent() {

    # get charge of all batteries, combine them
    total_charge=$(expr $(acpi -b | awk '{print $4}' | grep -Eo "[0-9]+" | paste -sd+ | bc));

    # get amount of batteries in the device
    battery_number=$(acpi -b | wc -l);

    percent=$(expr $total_charge / $battery_number);

    echo $percent;
}

get_battery_charging_status() {

    if $(acpi -b | grep --quiet Discharging)
    then
        echo "Discharging";
    else # acpi can give Unknown or Charging if charging, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203741/lenovo-t440s-battery-status-unknown-but-charging
        echo "Charging";
    fi
}

echo "All batteries: $(get_battery_charging_status) $(get_battery_combined_percent)%, $(get_time_until_charged ) remaining";
```

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! Note, only posting scripts/core/commands is not a very HQ answer. Explain what is does and how.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens it outputs the average percent of all batteries combined, how long it'll take for all batteries to fully charge (if device is plugged in) or completely empty (if not plugged in), and says if the device is being charged, in the format "All batteries: Discharging 90%, 10:10:06 remaining" (with different numbers of course). I've never written a bash script before, sorry if it's confusing

Comment: much better now!

Comment: I *believe* this will give an incorrect answer for the percentage if the batteries have different capacities. For example, if one battery has max charge C and the other charge 2C, then if one is depleted and the other is full, it will report 50%, I think (rather than the correct answer of either 33% or 66%).